# How to merge a lot of square images via OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

How can I merge images like below into a single image using OpenCV (there can be any number of them both horizontally and vertically)? Is there any built-in solution to do it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Additional pieces:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to solve the puzzle?

Comment: It seems you need some kind of image stitching. There is some stitching functional in OpenCV, but AFAIK, images should overlap a bit.

Answer (score 10):

Well, it seems that I finished the puzzle:

[image]

Main steps:

1. Compare each pair of images (*puzzle pieces*) to know the relative position (`findRelativePositions` and `getPosition`).
2. Build a map knowing the relative positions of the pieces (`buildPuzzle` and `builfForPiece`)
3. Create the final collage putting each image at the correct position (final part of `buildPuzzle`).

Comparison between pieces A and B in step 1 is done checking for similarity (sum of absolute difference) among:

- B is NORTH to A: A first row and B last row;
- B is SOUTH to A: A last row and B first row;
- B is WEST to A : A last column and B first column;
- B is EAST to A : A first column and B last column.

Since images do not overlap, but we can assume that confining rows (columns) are quite similar, the key aspect is to use a (ad-hoc) threshold to discriminate between confining pieces or not. This is handled in function `getPosition`, with threshold parameter `threshold`.

Here the full code. Please let me know if something is not clear.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

enum Direction
{
    NORTH = 0,
    SOUTH,
    WEST,
    EAST
};


int getPosition(const Mat3b& A, const Mat3b& B, double& cost)
{
    Mat hsvA, hsvB;
    cvtColor(A, hsvA, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    cvtColor(B, hsvB, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    int threshold = 1000;

    // Check NORTH
    Mat3b AN = hsvA(Range(0, 1), Range::all());
    Mat3b BS = hsvB(Range(B.rows - 1, B.rows), Range::all());

    Mat3b AN_BS;
    absdiff(AN, BS, AN_BS);
    Scalar scoreN = sum(AN_BS);

    // Check SOUTH
    Mat3b AS = hsvA(Range(A.rows - 1, A.rows), Range::all());
    Mat3b BN = hsvB(Range(0, 1), Range::all());

    Mat3b AS_BN;
    absdiff(AS, BN, AS_BN);
    Scalar scoreS = sum(AS_BN);

    // Check WEST
    Mat3b AW = hsvA(Range::all(), Range(A.cols - 1, A.cols));
    Mat3b BE = hsvB(Range::all(), Range(0, 1));

    Mat3b AW_BE;
    absdiff(AW, BE, AW_BE);
    Scalar scoreW = sum(AW_BE);

    // Check EAST
    Mat3b AE = hsvA(Range::all(), Range(0, 1));
    Mat3b BW = hsvB(Range::all(), Range(B.cols - 1, B.cols));

    Mat3b AE_BW;
    absdiff(AE, BW, AE_BW);
    Scalar scoreE = sum(AE_BW);

    vector<double> scores{ scoreN[0], scoreS[0], scoreW[0], scoreE[0] };
    int idx_min = distance(scores.begin(), min_element(scores.begin(), scores.end()));
    int direction = (scores[idx_min] < threshold) ? idx_min : -1;
    cost = scores[idx_min];
    return direction;
}

void resolveConflicts(Mat1i& positions, Mat1d& costs)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c)
    {
        // Search for duplicate pieces in each column

        set<int> pieces;
        set<int> dups;

        for (int r = 0; r < positions.rows; ++r)
        {
            int label = positions(r, c);
            if (label >= 0)
            {
                if (pieces.count(label) == 1)
                {
                    dups.insert(label);
                }
                else
                {
                    pieces.insert(label);
                }
            }
        }

        if (dups.size() > 0)
        {
            int min_idx = -1;
            for (int duplicate : dups)
            {
                // Find minimum cost position
                Mat1d column = costs.col(c);
                min_idx = distance(column.begin(), min_element(column.begin(), column.end()));

                // Keep only minimum cost position
                for (int ir = 0; ir < positions.rows; ++ir)
                {
                    int label = positions(ir, c);
                    if ((label == duplicate) && (ir != min_idx))
                    {
                        positions(ir, c) = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void findRelativePositions(const vector<Mat3b>& pieces, Mat1i& positions)
{
    positions = Mat1i(pieces.size(), 4, -1);
    Mat1d costs(pieces.size(), 4, DBL_MAX);

    for (int i = 0; i < pieces.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < pieces.size(); ++j)
        {
            double cost;
            int pos = getPosition(pieces[i], pieces[j], cost);

            if (pos >= 0)
            {
                if (costs(i, pos) > cost)
                {
                    positions(i, pos) = j;
                    costs(i, pos) = cost;
                    switch (pos)
                    {
                    case NORTH:
                        positions(j, SOUTH) = i;
                        costs(j, SOUTH) = cost;
                        break;
                    case SOUTH:
                        positions(j, NORTH) = i;
                        costs(j, NORTH) = cost;
                        break;
                    case WEST:
                        positions(j, EAST) = i;
                        costs(j, EAST) = cost;
                        break;
                    case EAST:
                        positions(j, WEST) = i;
                        costs(j, WEST) = cost;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    resolveConflicts(positions, costs);
}


void builfForPiece(int idx_piece, set<int>& posed, Mat1i& labels, const Mat1i& positions)
{
    Point pos(-1, -1);

    // Find idx_piece on grid;
    for (int r = 0; r < labels.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < labels.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (labels(r, c) == idx_piece)
            {
                pos = Point(c, r);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pos.x >= 0) break;
    }

    if (pos.x < 0) return;


    // Put connected pieces
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c)
    {
        int next = positions(idx_piece, c);
        if (next > 0)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
            case NORTH:
                labels(Point(pos.x, pos.y - 1)) = next;
                posed.insert(next);
                break;
            case SOUTH:
                labels(Point(pos.x, pos.y + 1)) = next;
                posed.insert(next);
                break;
            case WEST:
                labels(Point(pos.x + 1, pos.y)) = next;
                posed.insert(next);
                break;
            case EAST:
                labels(Point(pos.x - 1, pos.y)) = next;
                posed.insert(next);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


Mat3b buildPuzzle(const vector<Mat3b>& pieces, const Mat1i& positions, Size sz)
{
    int n_pieces = pieces.size();
    set<int> posed;
    set<int> todo;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_pieces; ++i) todo.insert(i);

    Mat1i labels(n_pieces * 2 + 1, n_pieces * 2 + 1, -1);

    // Place first element in the center
    todo.erase(0);
    labels(Point(n_pieces, n_pieces)) = 0;
    posed.insert(0);
    builfForPiece(0, posed, labels, positions);

    // Build puzzle starting from the already placed elements
    while (todo.size() > 0)
    {
        auto it = todo.begin();
        int next = -1;
        do
        {
            next = *it;
            ++it;
        } while (posed.count(next) == 0 && it != todo.end());


        todo.erase(next);
        builfForPiece(next, posed, labels, positions);
    }

    // Posed all pieces, now collage!

    vector<Point> pieces_position;
    Mat1b mask = labels >= 0;
    findNonZero(mask, pieces_position);
    Rect roi = boundingRect(pieces_position);

    Mat1i lbls = labels(roi);
    Mat3b collage(roi.height * sz.height, roi.width * sz.width, Vec3b(0, 0, 0));

    for (int r = 0; r < lbls.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < lbls.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (lbls(r, c) >= 0)
            {
                Rect rect(c*sz.width, r*sz.height, sz.width, sz.height);
                pieces[lbls(r, c)].copyTo(collage(rect));
            }
        }
    }

    return collage;
}


int main()
{
    // Load images

    vector<String> filenames;
    glob("D:\\SO\\img\\puzzle*", filenames);

    vector<Mat3b> pieces(filenames.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); ++i)
    {
        pieces[i] = imread(filenames[i], IMREAD_COLOR);
    }

    // Find Relative positions
    Mat1i positions;
    findRelativePositions(pieces, positions);

    // Build the puzzle
    Mat3b puzzle = buildPuzzle(pieces, positions, pieces[0].size());

    imshow("Puzzle", puzzle);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**

1. No, there is no built-in solution to perform this. Image stitching won't work since the images are not overlapped.
2. I cannot guarantee that this works for every puzzle, but should work for the most.
3. I probably should have worked this couple of hours, but it was fun :D

---

**EDIT**

Adding more puzzle pieces generates wrong results in the previous code version. This was due the (wrong) assumption that at most one piece is *good enough* to be connected with a given piece.

Now I added a cost matrix, and only the minimum cost piece is saved as neighbor of a given piece.
I added also a `resolveConflicts` function that avoid that one piece can be merged (in non-conflicting position) with more than one piece.

This is the result adding more pieces:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Considerations after increasing the number of puzzle pieces:

- This solution it's dependent on the input order of pieces, since it turns out it has a *greedy* approach to find neighbors.
- While searching for neighbors, it's better to compare the H channel in the HSV space. I updated the code above with this improvement.
- The final solution needs probably some kind of global minimization of the of a global cost matrix. This will make the method independent on the input order. I'll be back on this asap.

Comment: Hahahahahahaha. +1.  That last comment about work killed me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly in almost all other cases. For example, if you add to the initial set of images this image -- http://i.imgur.com/V76ZGav.png, you will find that it fails with merging

Comment: @Miki Thanks a lot! It'll be cool if you give me your Skype / email btw

Comment: Also it works ok if you add this image -- http://i.imgur.com/9nvR7sE.png, but not this image -- http://i.imgur.com/lJcZ5V3.png

Comment: @FrozenHeart updated code and description. Let me know.

Comment: @Miki Thanks a lot again! It fails on this set of files now -- http://imgur.com/a/07KRc

Comment: @FrozenHeart It make sense, border are not that discriminative here... There is make the comparison function more robust. I'll take a look tomorrow probably. Only if you promise no more images.. ;D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90368/discussion-between-frozenheart-and-miki).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have loaded this images as OpenCV Mat, you can concatenate these Mat both vertically or horizontally using:

```
Mat A, B; // Images that will be concatenated
Mat H; // Here we will concatenate A and B horizontally
Mat V; // Here we will concatenate A and B vertically
hconcat(A, B, H);
vconcat(A, B, V);
```

If you need to concatenate more than two images, you can use these methods recursively.

By the way, I think these methods are not included in the OpenCV documentation, but I have used them in the past.

Comment: No, you didn't understand me correctly. I don't know which images should be connected to other images exactly

Comment: Sorry for that. I suppose there are no built-in methods to solve this problem. However, it sould be easy comparing the first/last row/column of each square with the first/last row/column of the other squares and selecting the most similar one.

Comment: @FrozenHeart: I think you're looking for "image registration"