# compare pixels and sort

Tags: c++, opencv

This is kind of continue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134252/from-float-array-to-mat-concatenate-blocks-of-image).

I have an image 800x800 which is broken down to 16 blocks of 200x200.

I want to compare all the blocks between them in order to sort them in an order ( one image/block is continue of another ).

So , I thought to compare the pixels at the boundaries between blocks.

Since we have 16 blocks , they are laid as 4 rows x 4 cols.

For example, for first row we will have 4 blocks , so I am comparing the first with the second.I am comparing the last column of first block with the first column of second block ( their boundaries ) to see if they match ( if one image is the continuing of the other).Then , I am sorting them.

Because we have 4x4 dimensions , and because I am doing sort ( hence , I am using idx + 1 for the next block and idx for current ) I am applying the sort in every row.

(Right now , I am sorting only through rows)

The code is:

```
    vector<Mat> smallImages;
    vector<Rect> smallImageRois;

    Mat big1(800, 800, CV_32F); //write the blocks to this big image
    int big1step = big1.step1();
    float* pbig1 = big1.ptr<float>(0);

    // scan all the rows ( used for sort )
    for ( int k = 0; k < blocks_width * blocks_height; k++ )//width=height=4
    {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < blocks_width * blocks_height; ++idx)
        {
            float* pdata = (float*)smallImages[idx].data;
            int step = smallImages[idx].step1();
            Rect roi = smallImageRois[idx];

            for (int i = 0; i < smallSize.height; ++i)//height is 200
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < smallSize.width; ++j)//width is 200
                { 
                    //load the subimages to every roi
                    pbig1[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + j)] = smallImages[ idx ].at<int>(i*step+j);

                    //exclude indices 3,7,11,15 ( since we are already using idx + 1 ) in order to jump for every row
                    if ( idx != (blocks_width -1) && idx != (2 * blocks_width-1) && idx != (3 * blocks_width -1) 
                    && idx != blocks_width * blocks_height -1 )
                    {

                         //compare pixels at boundaries
                         // i am scaning for every row the first column (roi.x + 0 ) of the next image to the last column (roi.x + (subImageSize.width-1) of the previous
                         if ( abs( sqrt( pow( (pbig1+1)[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + 0)] , 2 ) -  pow(  pbig1[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + (subImageSize.width-1))] , 2 ) ) ) < 4 )
                            {

                                //do sort
                                int temp =  (pbig1+1)[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + j)];
                                (pbig1+1)[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + j)] = pbig1[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + j)];
                                pbig1[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + j)] = temp;

                            }
                       }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1) I am receiving exactly the same image as the original.No sort , no comparing!

2) I am using `smallImages[ idx ].at<int>(i*step+j);`  and not `pdata` that I declared in the loop because I can't understand why these two give different results:

```
smallImages[ 2 ].at<int>(i*step+j)
 (pdata+ 2)[ i * step + j ]  //doesn't this point to idx = 2?
```

Comment: Since this is your third question on the same problem that your trying to solve in the _wrong_ (or at least not best practice) way, I recommend you write a new question asking "how can I do this?" posting the code you have so far, and a **well explained** problem to solve. You'll probably find out that you can achieve your goal in a much easier way.

Comment: Just to clarify, your questions are perfectly valid. But you're probably missing the big picture...

Comment: @Miki:I will try to edit the question later but general , I have an image divided in regions(every region is an image) where the images are randomnly distributed in the whole image.So , I am trying to put them in the correct order and draw the original image.That's why I am comparing pixels ( at boundary positions)  for each block in every  row , I am sorting them , then move to the next row and so on . ( the same code then needs to be run for every column to sort them also) .I hope it is more clear?Thanks!

Comment: Check through my answers. I already answered to something like this. The answer didn't work in general as it's right now, but can be a good place to start. (I'll give you the link asap, I can't now). Also, as an advice, stop working with raw pointers. You're making this much harder than it should be, and gaining just few milliseconds.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32722778/5008845) is the answer I'm referring to. Also, I think that your problem is quite interesting. If you post a new well written question, you may get useful answers. This one is fine as it is.

Comment: @Miki:Indeed ,is a puzzle,conect the pieces to acquire the correct image.I will look at your posts and mine tomorrow again.Thank you very much.