# How to compare images and conbine into one image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a problem as follows, i have about 30 pieces of an image and i want to combine it into one like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zWHm.jpg) image. How or any library in python can do that?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Is there any order any clue from file names ? How the program will know which piece will be where?

Comment: I think the program will compare 2 images and order them based on border, i have no idea it wanna be so i asking for some helps..

Comment: i found the source where basicaly same idea with me but simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719864/how-to-merge-a-lot-of-square-images-via-opencv

Answer (score -1):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

im1 = cv2.imread('data/abc1.jpg')
im2 = cv2.imread('data/abc2.jpg')

im_v = cv2.vconcat([im1, im1])
cv2.imwrite('data/dst/opencv_vconcat.jpg', im_v)
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete (show only one vertical concatenation), incorrect (concatenates an image with itself, ignoring the second image), not formatted correctly, and does not explain what you are doing.